# keyError no message

Tags: python, keyerror

I'm in the process of dealing with some code that should work. But, im continuing to get

> for match in matches['matches']:
>   KeyError: 'matches'

, which should have a value. I've already checked/double checked to make sure it was returning a value.

```
    def handle_data(self, data):
    players = data
    teams = {}
    myStats = []
    enStats = []

    # Seperate the players by team
    for player in players:
        if player["teamId"] == 100:
            teams.setdefault("team A", []).append(player)
        else:
            teams.setdefault("team B", []).append(player)

    if self.check_team(teams['team A']):
        self.find_my_lane(teams['team A'])
        self.find_e_lane(teams['team B'])
    else:
        self.find_my_lane(teams['team B'])
        self.find_e_lane(teams['team A'])


def find_my_lane(self, team):
    lane_list = {}
    for player in team:
        if player['summonerId'] == self.summoner_id:
            self.champion_id = player['championId']
    matches = self.get_match_list(self.summoner_id, self.champion_id)
    for match in matches['matches']:
        if match['lane'] in lane_list:
            lane_list[match['lane']] += 1
        else:
            lane_list[match['lane']] = 1
    for lane in lane_list:
        rate = (float(lane_list[lane]) / len(matches['matches'])) * 100
        if rate > 40.0:
            self.lane.append(lane)
            break

def find_e_lane(self, team):
    """

    :rtype : object
    """
    e_lane_list = []
    lane_opp = []
    e_matches = {}
    assert isinstance(team, object)
    for player in team:
        e_matches = self.get_match_list(player['summonerId'], player['championId'])
        for match in e_matches['matches']:
            if match['lane'] in e_lane_list:
                e_lane_list[match['lane']] += 1
            else:
                e_lane_list[match['lane']] = 1
        for e_lane in e_lane_list:
            rate = (float(e_lane_list[e_lane]) / len(e_matches['matches'])) * 100
            if (40.0 < rate) and (e_lane in self.lane):
                lane_opp.append(player['summonerId'])
                lane_opp.append(player['championId'])
        if not lane_opp:
            continue
        else:
            break
    self.e_summoner = lane_opp[0]
    self.e_champion = lane_opp[1]
```

if you need any details, or specification, I can provide it

Comment: Well, `self.get_match_list` returns a dictionary. However, it doesn't have a key `'matches'`. Have you tried printing out `matches` to see what sort of structure it has?

Comment: Yes, i've done that. I've already verified each elements.

Comment: You can verify as much as you like; the interpreter always has the final say, and it says no such key exists. Can you provide a small sample of those data, or some other approach toward a [mcve]?